# How to get load balancer data from google compute engine?

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-platform

I have searched the various APIs including stackdriver and https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/apis but cannot find any that return load balancing data.

This API returns the data I need but it seems to be an internal API used by google. `network.googleapis.com/loadbalancer/requests`

Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by load balancer data? Are you looking for a LoadBalancer resource? GCE load balancer is a feature including a group of resources, e.g. forwarding rule, backend service, url map, instance group...

Comment: Basically I need RPS on the load balancer for datadog.The google console UI uses the following call for RPS network.googleapis.com/loadbalancer/requests - displaying RPS. I am unable to get this data as it is an internal API. I have looked everywhere including where you have mentioned but cannot find an API that gives RPS.